# Setting attribute in callable context manager decorator from decorated function

Tags: python, python-decorators, callable, contextmanager

I'm playing around with context managers and decorators in Python and made a callable context-manager decorator class. I have it decorating a function where I want to modify an attribute in the decorator class. Here's a simple version of the decorator class:

```
class CallableDecorator:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Creating decorator')
        self.foo = None
    def __enter__(self):
        print('Entering Decorator')
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print(f'Exiting Decorator with attribute foo = {self.foo}')
    def __call__(self, func):
        print('Starting the call in Decorator')
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with self:
                print('In wrapped context manager')
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('About to finish call in Decorator')
        return wrapper
```

Then I'm wrapping a function like

```
@CallableDecorator()
def bar():
    something = do_stuff()
    setattr(callable_decorator, 'foo', something)
    print('bar')
```

And this will immediately print

```
Creating decorator
Starting the call in Decorator
About to finish call in Decorator
```

Because this is pretty much calling `CallableDecorator()bar()`, so an object of type `CallableDecorator` is being created when this function is made. After calling `bar()`, this is printed:

```
Entering Decorator
In wrapped context manager
bar
Exiting Decorator with foo = None
```

Which is also expected because now I'm calling the `wrapper`. However, I want to change the `foo` attribute in the `CallableDecorator` from `bar` with a value that is calculated in the `bar` function, but is not known at the time of defining `bar`. Is there anyway to access this?

I'm not asking if this is a good design or when this would ever be useful, I'm just trying to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the wrapper pass the decorator object itself as a parameter when it calls `func`:

```
class CallableDecorator:
    def __call__(self, func):
        print('Starting the call in Decorator')
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with self:
                print('In wrapped context manager')
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print('About to finish call in Decorator')
        return wrapper
```

so that `func` can accept the decorator object as a parameter and set its `foo` attribute inside the function:

```
@CallableDecorator()
def bar(decorator):
    decorator.foo = 'bar'
```

With these changes, your code would output:

```
Creating decorator
Starting the call in Decorator
About to finish call in Decorator
Entering Decorator
In wrapped context manager
Exiting Decorator with attribute foo = bar
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit about that. The value that I'm wanting to update isn't known at the time of defining bar. It's something that will be created inside `bar`.